# How does this.unblock work in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

How does `this.unblock` work in Meteor?

The docs say:

```
Call inside a method invocation. Allow subsequent method from this client to begin running in a new fiber.

On the server, methods from a given client run one at a time. The N+1th invocation from a client won't start until the Nth invocation returns. However, you can change this by calling this.unblock. This will allow the N+1th invocation to start running in a new fiber.
```

How can new code start running in a new fiber if Node runs in a single thread? Does it only unblock when we get to an I/O request, but no unblock would happen if we were running a long computation?

Answer (score 1):

Fibers are an abstraction layer on top of Node's Event Loop. They change how we write code to interact with the Event Loop, but they do not change how Node works. Meteor, among other things, is sort of an API to Fibers.

Each client request in Meteor creates a new fiber. Meteor methods called by the client, by default, will queue up behind each other. This is the default behavior likely because there is an assumption that you want Mongo up to date for all clients before continuing execution. However, if you do not need your clients to work with the latest up to date globals or data, you can use this.unblock() to put each of these client requests in Node's Event Loop without waiting for the previous to complete. However, we are still constrained to Node's Event Loop.

So this.unblock() works by allowing all client requests to that method enter the Event Loop (non IO blocking execution based on callbacks). However, as Node is still a single threaded application, CPU intensive operations will block the callbacks in the Event Loop. That is why Node is not a good choice for CPU intensive work, and that doesn't change with Meteor or Meteor's interaction with Fibers/the Event Loop.

A simple analogy: The Event Loop, or our single Node thread, is a highway. Each car on the highway is a complex event driven function that will eventually exit off the highway when its callbacks complete. Fibers allow us to more easily control who gets on the highway and when. Meteor methods allow a single car on the highway at a time by default, but when properly using this.unblock() you allow multiple cars on the highway. However, a CPU intensive operation on any fiber will cause a traffic jam. I/O and network will not.